# Segmentation Fault issues

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, strtok

I have a program that is supposed to decrypt an encrypted text file using a shift cipher. In my main loop where I cycle through `shift` options, I get a segmentation fault with `strtok`. It works fine the first time around, but then when I go through the loop a second time and call `strtok` with the NULL pointer, I get the error. I'm not very familiar with `strtok` but I used a temp variable that resets my input array after every loop to deal with the string reformatting.

Also, I get another segmentation fault in `check_dict` when the word is not in the dictionary file. When it can find the word, it works fine, so I'm assuming the loop can't find the NULL pointer so it tries to reference an invalid address. Any ideas?

EDIT: I've updated my code. `strtok` works fine now. My only problem is my `check_dict` function. Is it something to do with my initialization of the dictionary array. The file I'm pulling from has one word on each line. I end the array with NULL, but my `check_dict` function can't seem to find it in the loop and I get a segmentation fault.

```
typedef struct {
    int shift, num_right;
} Shift_Op; // best shift option

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fp; // input file pointer
    FILE *dict_file; // dictionary file pointer
    Shift_Op best_shift; // struct for ship options
    char **dict, **word; // dictionary array
    char *chars, *inp, *t;
    int i, j, c, num, wc=0, cc=0, shift=1;

    // check command-line arguments
    if (argc==1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please enter a file for decryption.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (argc==2) {
        if (((fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL) || ((dict_file=fopen("../../../../usr/share/dict/words","r"))==NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if (argc==3) {
        if ((fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if ((dict_file=fopen(argv[2],"r"))==NULL) {
            if ((dict_file=fopen("../../../../usr/share/dict/words","r"))==NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not open given dictoinary file or backup file.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else
                printf("Could not open given dictionary file, using backup instead.\n");
        }
    }

    //get file stats for dictionary
    file_stats(dict_file, &cc, &wc);
    rewind(dict_file);
    // check memory allocation
    if ((chars=(char *) malloc(cc+1))==NULL)
        return 1;
    if ((dict=(char **) malloc((wc+1)*sizeof(char *)))==NULL)
        return 1;
    if ((word=(char **) malloc((CHECK_WORD_LIMIT+1)*sizeof(char *)))==NULL)
        return 1;

    file_stats(fp, &cc, &wc);
    rewind(fp);
    if (((inp=(char *) malloc(cc+1))==NULL) || ((t=(char *) malloc(cc+1))==NULL))
        return 1;

    // input files into arrays
    input_dict(dict_file, chars, dict);
    input_file(fp, inp);
    t = inp; // temp array for strtok
    best_shift.num_right = 0;

    // loop through string tokens
    word[0] = strtok(t, " .,?!;:-/\"\n");
    for (i=1; i<CHECK_WORD_LIMIT; i++) {
        word[i] = strtok(NULL, " .,?!;:-/\"\n");
    }

    // loop through shift options
    while (shift<25) {
        printf("Checking shift = %d\n", shift);
        num = 0;
        for (j=0; j<CHECK_WORD_LIMIT; j++) { // loop through words at beginning of file

            if (check_dict(shift_string(word[i], shift), dict)) // check if token is in dictionary array
                num++;

            printf("%s\n", shift_string(word[j], shift));
        }

        if (num>best_shift.num_right) { // if shift option gives more correct words
            best_shift.shift = shift; // change best shift option
            best_shift.num_right = num;
        }
        shift++;
    }

    shift = best_shift.num_right;
    //while ((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF) { // output shifted file
    //  putchar(shift_char(c, shift));
    //}

    free(dict);
    free(chars);
    free(word);
    free(inp);
    free(t);

    return 0;
}

char shift_char(char c, int k) {
    return (tolower(c)-k);
}

char *shift_string(char *s, int k) {
    char *t;
    int i = 0;
    if ((t = (char *) malloc(strlen(s)))==NULL)
        return NULL;

    while (*s!='\0') {
        t[i] = shift_char(*s, k);
        s++;
        i++;
    }
    t[i]=='\0';
    return t;
}

int check_dict(char *w, char **d) {
    int i = 0;
    while (strcasecmp(w, d[i]) && (d[i]!=NULL))
        i++;
    return (!strcasecmp(w, d[i]));
}


void input_dict(FILE *d, char *chars, char **words) {

    int c, i = 0, j = 1;

    words[0] = &chars[0];

    while ((c=fgetc(d))!=EOF) {

        if (c=='\n') {
            words[j] = &chars[i+1];
            j++;
            c = '\0';
        }

        chars[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    words[j] = NULL;
    chars[i] = '\0';
}

void input_file(FILE *f, char *inp) {
    int c;
    while ((c=fgetc(f))!=EOF) {
        *inp = c;
        inp++;
    }
}

void file_stats(FILE *d, int *cc, int *wc) {
    int c;
    while ((c=fgetc(d))!=EOF) {
        (*cc)++;

        if (c=='\n')
            (*wc)++;
    }
    (*wc)++;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for Shift_Op as well?

Comment: `shift_string` returns a not 0-terminated string.

Comment: `strtok` may return `NULL` to indicate that there are no more tokens. You should test for this value. The first thing you do to the string in `shift_string` is to call `strlen` on it, which will (or might) fail for `NULL`. (`strtok` is usually called in a `while` loop with the first call outside the loop, not in side fixed-length `for` loops.)

Comment: Don't post this much code, but only the essential parts. IAW, don't ask to wade through a complete program, but do the hard work of zooming in to your problem first. Usually you'll find the problem yourself doing so.

Comment: Something else: `strtok` modifies the string; it overwrites the delimiters with `'\0'` so that the tokens are null-terminated string. When tokenising the same string a second time, there will be only one token, so the second call to `strtok` on an already tokenised string (with the same delimiters, of course) will be `NULL`. Your tokenisation loop is inside another while loop. Consider creating a copy of the string on which you do the tokenisation. Or tokenise only once before the `while` loop and keep an array of the tokens.

Comment: `if ((t = (char *) malloc(strlen(s)))==NULL)` should (at least) be `if ((t = malloc(1+strlen(s)))==NULL)`

Comment: A few other things to consider:  in your check_dict function, you should be checking your pointers for NULL before passing them to strcasecmp. You check for d[i] != NULL, but this is after you have already passed it to strcasecmp.  Place this particular check before the call to strcasecmp; short-circuit evaluation will prevent you from calling strcasecmp to begin with this way

Comment: Also, you check d[i] for being NULL, which is good.  But checking this element for NULL is actually dereferencing d in the process.  You want to check for d != NULL before going into your while loop, then a better conditional to the while loop would be "while ((d[i] != NULL) && strcasecmp(w, d[i]))"

Comment: After your changes, `word[i]` might still be `NULL` when your original input has fewer than `CHECK_WORD_LIMIT` tokens. You don't check that in the `while (shift < 25) ...` loop. Check for `NULL` and `break` out of the loop before calling your functions.